# ansible - json_query compare a boolean with an external var

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to do a test in ansible inside a json_query by comparing a value of my dict to an other variable of my playbook:

My dict:

```
cust_pkg:
  - { name: "a" }
  - { name: "b", web: true }
```

I'd like as output:

When web_host is true

```
dict_pkg:
  - { name: "a" }
  - { name: "b", web: true }
```

Otherwise (web_host false or undefined)

```
 dict_pkg:
  - { name: "a" }
```

I'm trying like that:

```
- set_fact:
    dict_pkg: "{{ cust_pkg | json_query(\"[?web == '\" + web_host + \"']\") }}"
```

But, I've got this error:

```
{"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ cust_pkg | json_query(\"[?web == '\" + web_host + \"']\") }}): cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool' objects"}
```

How can I do then to filter depending on an external boolean variable?

Thanks

Comment: Post cust_pkg and desired dict_pkg.

Comment: Added in initial message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, that's do the trick:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    cust_pkg:
      - { name: "a" }
      - { name: "b", web: true }

  tasks:

  - name: Step 1
    debug:
      msg: "{{ cust_pkg | json_query(\"[?web == nul || web == `\" + (web_host|default('false')|lower) + \"`]\") }}"
```

With output:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Step 1] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "a"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

And:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars="web_host=true"

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Step 1] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "a"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "b", 
            "web": true
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

> cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool' objects

How much clearer would you like the error message to be?

What you'll want is to explicitly coerce that value to a `str` so the types match up:

```
dict_pkg: "{{ cust_pkg | json_query(\"[?web == `\" + (web_host|lower) + \"`]\") }}"
```

Next you'll likely want to consider changing the yaml construct to avoid the quoting hell:

```
dict_pkg: >-
   {{ cust_pkg | json_query("[?web == `" + (web_host|lower) + "`]") }}
```

Comment: Seems not to work: `"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'str' is undefined...`

Comment: Damn, I'm sorry! I usually do actually try the things before suggesting them but I thought this one was so "simple" that I didn't :-( But, had I actually tested the answer first, I would have realized that you need backticks in jmespath to use a literal `true` or `false`, and not the single quotes like you were trying before. I have updated my answer with all of that